# Ruby: Checking if URI is HTTPS?

Tags: ruby, https, uri

I would like to check if the URI will need SSL authentication:

```
url = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")

# [some code]

if url.instance_of? URI::HTTPS
   http.use_ssl=true
   http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end
```

However, those few lines throw the following error..

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:436:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): HTTPS (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:485:in `parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:608:in `URI'
    from links.rb:18
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: By the way, https://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/ explains why `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` is not the best choice

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
>> uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x1014ca458 URL:http://www.google.com>
>> uri.scheme
=> "http"
>> uri = URI.parse("https://mail.google.com")
=> #<URI::HTTPS:0x1014c2e60 URL:https://mail.google.com>
>> uri.scheme
=> "https"
```

So you could check uri's scheme against simple "https" string.

Answer (score 9):

as shown in the previous answer, `HTTP` and `HTTPS` are different classes.
in particular, `HTTPS` is a subclass of the `HTTP` class. thus you could check with `instance_of?`.

```
http  = URI.parse "http://example.com"
https = URI.parse "https://example.com"

http.instance_of?  URI::HTTPS  #=> false
https.instance_of? URI::HTTPS  #=> true
```

but if this hierarchy ever gets changed, then your code could break, thus the above answer might be more future-proof.

Comment: The probability of changing class hierarchy is basically the same as with `scheme` method, IMHO. Standard library is still quite stable. `instance_of?(URI::HTTPS)` can be a better choice since if I mistype a string (say `http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'htps')`), I get no error, whereas `instance_of?(URI::HTPS)` gives `uninitialized constant`